# Xamarin Android App not working (Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, sdk

When I create a android phone project there is an error which I can't resolve, the sdk and other things are installed.

My Error:
[image]

Comment: Please add the `Version Information and Logs`: In Visual Studio, version information can be copied from: Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio -> Copy Info button and the log files can be gathered from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\Log`

Answer (score 0):

Try starting Visual Studio as Administrator, that fixed it for me.